# Mongoose/mongdb not updating the database properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I am having issues where the database isn't updating properly:

```
User.updateOne({_id: id}, {
   $inc: {thonk: 1}
 }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
    session.userdata.thonk++;
    data = session.userdata.username + ' You auto thonked a total of ' + session.userdata.thonk;
     session.userdata.autos--;
     session.save();
     battle(io, socket);
     io.sockets.connected[socket.id].emit('auto-result', data); 
 });
```

If I console the results: `{  n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }`

Here is the schema for the User model. What is weird is I had tested this before, and it worked. Now it just doesn't want to.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  username:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password:{
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  registered: {
    type: String,
    default: today
  },
  rank: {
    type: Number,
    default: 1
  },
  currency: {
    type: Object,
    default: {
      cs: 100,
      os: 100
    },
  },
  thonk: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes it is, I'll update post with my schema

Comment: Can you ensure that the `{ _id: id }` exists? I mean there is an object with the `id`?

Comment: Yes. The id is the person who is logged in.

Comment: I figured it out, I wasn't defining my session correctly. Thanks!